# Symfony2 - FOSUserBundle - Check for password confirmation mismatch on custom reset page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am building out a custom form for users to reset their password. Everything thing is done except checking for password mismatch. No error is given when then 2 entered fields don't match - but the form will reload empty, so I know that it is caught

In the the form vars dump I have {{ dump(form.new.first.vars.errors) }}

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)#251 (4) {
["message":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormError":private]=>
string(26) "fos_user.password.mismatch"
["messageTemplate":protected]=>
string(26) "fos_user.password.mismatch"
["messageParameters":protected]=>
array(1) {
  ["{{ value }}"]=>
  string(5) "array"
}
["messagePluralization":protected]=>
NULL
 }
```

}

Here is how I display the form

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 single">
        <div class="panel r-panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"> 
                <h1>Enter New Password</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form action="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_reset', {'token': token}) }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_resetting_reset">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="{{form.new.first.vars.id}}"> Password
                     <span class="text-primary">*</span>
                  </label>
                  {{ form_widget(form.new.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}   
              </div>
                 <label for="{{form.new.second.vars.id}}"> Confirm
                   <span class="text-primary">*</span>
                 </label>
                {{ form_widget(form.new.second, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}   
              </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />
          </div>
         {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping in the twig code that I can add something like

```
{% if passwords_mismatch %} ERROR! {% endif %}
```

Comment: The error may show up on the entire form, in which case you don't have a method to show those errors. Did you try adding `{{ form_errors(form) }}` after your `<form>` tag?

Comment: That would work, but I am trying to test for this specific error

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use the repeated form type that is available for Symfony2 forms.
This can replace the 2 input fields that you use.
The repeated form field shows 2 input fields, and checks if they are equal.

You should set add `'error_bubbling' => true` to the repeated field

for more info about repeated form type see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

For example:

```
$builder->add('new', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'DocdataUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat password'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch'))
```